# Вывод преобразованного массива

Tags: c#

Нужно заменить нули в целочисленном массиве полусуммой последующего и предыдущего чисел (если 0 содержится в первом или последнем элементе, то необходимо взять 1/2 второго или предпоследнего чисел соответственно).Вторую часть пока не делал, но первая почему-то выводит значения полученное в результате обработки, а не преобразованный массив
Например исходный массив 2 0 4 - выводит 3 3 3

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int k = 0;
        int count = textBoxISX.Lines.Length;
        int[] mas = new int[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            mas[i] = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxISX.Lines[i]);

        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            if (mas[j] == 0)

                k = (mas[j - 1] + mas[j + 1]) / 2;
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    mas[i] = k;
                textBoxVIH.Clear();







        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            textBoxVIH.AppendText(mas[i] + Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все дело в этом куске:

```
for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            if (mas[j] == 0)

                k = (mas[j - 1] + mas[j + 1]) / 2;
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    mas[i] = k;
                textBoxVIH.Clear();
```

У вас сначала выполняется:

```
for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
                if (mas[j] == 0)
                    k = (mas[j - 1] + mas[j + 1]) / 2;
```

А потом всем элементам массива присваивается `k`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    mas[i] = k;
```

Для вашей задачи будет достаточно вот такого цикла:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    if (i != 0 && i!= count)
        mas[i] = (mas[i-1] + mas[i+1]) / 2;
    else if (i == 0)
        mas[i] = mas[i+1] / 2;
    else
        mas[i] = mas[i-1] / 2;
}
```